# Lua unit testing framewok for embedded systems

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, lua

I'm just curious, what is a good Lua framework for unit-testing on embedded systems. I heard about Lunit and Lua Unit, but do these libraries work fine on embedded systems?

Comment: as far as I understand from my little investigation, the best unit testing package for lua on embedded system is lunatest. It has more functions than lunit, and does not overwrite standart lua functions. So if anyone is interested, here it is - https://github.com/silentbicycle/lunatest

Comment: you might want to make that comment an answer so it can be upvoted... it is perfectly fair to answer your own questions here at SO after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand from my little investigation, the best unit testing package for lua on embedded system is lunatest. It has more functions than lunit, and does not overwrite standard lua functions. So if anyone is interested, here it is - https://github.com/silentbicycle/lunatest

Comment: The only snag I found on lunatest is that it's done for Lua 5.1, if you want to run it with C API you have to activate LUA_COMPAT_MODULE.